# regex grab email from one long string of characters

Tags: regex, grep

I have a large text file that is one insanely long string of characters. My goal is to extract all of the email addresses that come between "personEmail" and "created", there are other emails in the file but I would like just those specific ones. I would also like to count the number of occurances of each email address in the text file, below is an extract:

> GFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS9mNWQzMGMyYi1mZDMyLTRhYTYtYjZhYS1iYTdkYWNjZWZiN2M","personEmail":"user1@provider.com","created":"2016-07-13T19:19:14.934Z","html":"blah-mention data-object-type=\"person\" data-objectid=\"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1user2@provider.comBFT1BMRS81MjhlZDZiMi1jODM4LTQzNDAtOWE2ZC0xMmRmYzI5YWU5

I was hoping to achieve it with `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` and maybe count with `uniq -c` if possible, I know how to do this using `regex` if there is multiple strings but not if the file is just one really long string in itself. is there a quick solution to this?

Comment: As per your sample text, you can match the emails with this regex:  `personEmail":"(\w+@(?:\w+\.)+\w+)"`  (you may improve the email regex as you wish, there are lots of samples out there).

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
(?<="personEmail":")[^"]+(?=")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- find the value associated to the `personEmail` field

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/aH1nO9/2

**Sample text**

> GFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS9mNWQzMGMyYi1mZDMyLTRhYTYtYjZhYS1iYTdkYWNjZWZiN2M","personEmail":"user1@provider.com","created":"2016-07-13T19:19:14.934Z","html":"blah-mention data-object-type=\"person\" data-objectid=\"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1user2@provider.comBFT1BMRS81MjhlZDZiMi1jODM4LTQzNDAtOWE2ZC0xMmRmYzI5YWU5

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
0.  [87-105]    `user1@provider.com`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "personEmail":"          '"personEmail":"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```